Integers into random order with constraints in R?
I want to sample integers in R, but also set constraints that for example, "3 comes always before 2" and "8 comes always before 5".
EDIT: The integers need not to be next to each other, for example, c(x,3,y,2,z) and c(8,x,y,z,5) are both acceptable, given these constraints.
Without any constraints one could just write:
sample(1:10)

...and that's it, but now we need something more. I like to think with tables or matrices so describing the relations with a matrix was my solution to this problem i.e.
# Create constraint matrix
constraint_matrix <- matrix(0, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)

# Set constraints
constraint_matrix[3, 2] <- 1  # 3 comes before 2
constraint_matrix[8, 5] <- 1  # 8 comes before 5

# Check, if generated output satisfies set constraints
check_constraints <- function(numbers, constraint_matrix) {
  for (i in 1:(length(numbers) - 1)) {
    if (constraint_matrix[numbers[i+1], numbers[i]] == 1) {
      return(FALSE)  # A constraint NOT satisfied
    }
  }
  return(TRUE)  # All constraints are satisfied
}

# Generate random order and check if constraints are satisfies
set.seed(123)
numbers <- sample(1:10)

while (!check_constraints(numbers, contstraint_matrix)) {
  numbers <- sample(1:10)
}

print(numbers)


My question is whether there is a better, optimized function to do this? Or does someone know a better algorithm for this task?

Does 3 have to be immediately be followed by 2, like in c(3, 2, ...) or in c(..., 3, 2, ...)? Or is something like c(3, ..., 2, ...) also allowed?

Are you always sampling without replacement?

This problem is a random topological sort of a DAG. A few links may be useful: link1, link2, link3, link4.

@FelixJassler The integers need not to be next to each other, I'll clarify this.

@CarlWitthoft I am always sampling without replacement.

Check if the order follows constraints, if not then just swap their positions:
set.seed(1); x <- sample(1:10)
x
# [1]  9  4  7  1  2  5  3 10  6  8

#"3 comes always before 2" and "8 comes always before 5".
cons <- list(c(3, 2), c(8, 5))

for(i in seq_along(cons)){
  ix <- match(cons[[ i ]], x)
  if(ix[ 1 ] > ix[ 2 ]) x[ rev(ix) ] <- cons[[ i ]]
  }

x
# [1]  9  4  7  1  3  8  2 10  6  5


Your request is unclear.  Here's a simple way 2 and 5 follow any desired values.
samp <- 1:10
lastones <- c(2,5)
foo <- sample(samp[-lastones])
foo <- c(foo, lastones)

